# How to load data from the online GAE datastore into the local development server?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, database-backups, bulkloader

I have previously used the approach described in [GAE docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata#Loading_Data_Into_the_Development_Server) to download backups of my entities on the live datastore.

Currently, I have a csv file per entity kind, that I got by writing `bulkloader.yaml` and using this command:

```
appcfg.py download_data --config_file=bulkloader.yaml --filename=users.csv --kind=Permission --url=http://your_app_id.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api
```

I also have a sql3 dump file that I got using the command:

```
appcfg.py download_data --kind=<kind> --url=http://your_app_id.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api --filename=<data-filename>
```

Now if I try this command:

```
appcfg.py upload_data --url=http://your_app_id.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api --kind=<kind> --filename=<data-filename>
```

Replacing the URL by localhost:8080, it asks me for a username/password. Now even if provide a mock username (test@example.com) in `http://localhost:8080/_ah/remote_api` and check the "admin" checkbox, it always gives me an authentication error.

The other alternative mentioned in the docs is using this:

```
appcfg.py upload_data --config_file=album_loader.py --filename=album_data.csv --kind=Album --url=http://localhost:8080/_ah/remote_api <app-directory>
```

I wrote a loader, and tried it out, it also asks for a username and password, but it accepts anything here. The output is as follows:

```
/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/search/search.py:232: UserWarning: DocumentOperationResult._code is deprecated. Use OperationResult._code instead.
  'Use OperationResult.%s instead.' % (name, name))
/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/search/search.py:232: UserWarning: DocumentOperationResult._CODES is deprecated. Use OperationResult._CODES instead.
  'Use OperationResult.%s instead.' % (name, name))
Application: knowledgetestgame
Uploading data records.
[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20121113.210613
[INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
[INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second
[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
[INFO    ] Opening database: bulkloader-progress-20121113.210613.sql3
Please enter login credentials for localhost
Email: test@example.com
Password for test@example.com: 
[INFO    ] Connecting to localhost:8080/_ah/remote_api
[INFO    ] Starting import; maximum 10 entities per post
[ERROR   ] [WorkerThread-4] WorkerThread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/adaptive_thread_pool.py", line 176, in WorkOnItems
    status, instruction = item.PerformWork(self.__thread_pool)
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 764, in PerformWork
    transfer_time = self._TransferItem(thread_pool)
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 933, in _TransferItem
    self.content = self.request_manager.EncodeContent(self.rows)
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 1394, in EncodeContent
    entity = loader.create_entity(values, key_name=key, parent=parent)
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 2728, in create_entity
    (len(self.__properties), len(values)))
AssertionError: Expected 17 columns, found 18.
[INFO    ] [WorkerThread-5] Backing off due to errors: 1.0 seconds
[INFO    ] Unexpected thread death: WorkerThread-4
[INFO    ] An error occurred. Shutting down...
[ERROR   ] Error in WorkerThread-4: Expected 17 columns, found 18.

[INFO    ] 980 entities total, 0 previously transferred
[INFO    ] 0 entities (278 bytes) transferred in 5.9 seconds
[INFO    ] Some entities not successfully transferred
```

I have ~4000 entities in total, it says here that 980 are transferred, but actually I check the local datastore and I find none of them..

Below is the loader I use (I used `NDB` for the Guess entity)

```
import datetime
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.tools import bulkloader
from google.appengine.ext.ndb import key


class Guess(db.Model):
    pass

class GuessLoader(bulkloader.Loader):
    def __init__(self):
        bulkloader.Loader.__init__(self, 'Guess',
                                   [('selectedAssociation', lambda x: x.decode('utf-8')),
                                    ('suggestionsList', lambda x: x.decode('utf-8')),
                                    ('associationIndexInList', int),                                    
                                    ('timeEntered',
                                     lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y').date()),
                                    ('rank', int),
                                    ('topicName', lambda x: x.decode('utf-8')),
                                    ('topic', int),
                                    ('player', int),
                                    ('game', int),
                                    ('guessString', lambda x: x.decode('utf-8')),
                                    ('guessTime',
                                     lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y').date()),
                                    ('accountType', lambda x: x.decode('utf-8')),
                                    ('nthGuess', int),
                                    ('score', float),
                                    ('cutByRoundEnd', bool),
                                    ('suggestionsListDelay', int),
                                    ('occurrences', float)
                                   ])

loaders = [GuessLoader]
```

Edit: I just noticed this part in the error message `[ERROR   ] Error in WorkerThread-0: Expected 17 columns, found 18.` while actually I just went through the whole csv file, and made sure that every line has 18 columns. I checked the loader, and found that I was missing the `key` column, I gave it a type `int` but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

If you have problems with the authentication, put the following in your appengine_config.py:

```
if os.environ.get('SERVER_SOFTWARE','').startswith('Development'):
    remoteapi_CUSTOM_ENVIRONMENT_AUTHENTICATION = (
    'REMOTE_ADDR', ['127.0.0.1'])
```

then run

```
appcfg.py download_data --url=http://APPNAME.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api --filename=dump --kind=EntityName
appcfg.py upload_data --url=http://localhost:8080/_ah/remote_api --filename=dump --application=dev~APPNAME
```

Answer (score 1):

Try just pressing `Enter` (no username/password). This seemed to do the trick for me. My command (wrapped in a bash script to prevent import errors that I occasionally received) is:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Modify path
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:.

# Load data
python /path/to/app/config/appcfg.py upload_data \
--config_file=<my_loader.py> \
--filename=<output.csv> \
--kind=<kind> \
--application=dev~<application_id> \
--url=http://localhost:8088/_ah/remote_api ./
```

When prompted for the `Email`, I hit enter and all is uploaded to the dev server. I am not using `NDB` in this case, although I do not believe that should make a difference.

Comment: @MohamedKhamis How many columns do you have in your CSV? That error takes the form of `Expected <number of items in config> columns, found <number of columns in CSV.`. I would suggest removing the `key`, but also going to the first column of the CSV that contains no data, pressing `Ctrl+Space`, then `Ctrl+Shift+Right Arrow` and then actually deleting the columns (`Alt+HDC` in Excel 2007, or just right click on a column header and hit delete). Then save - it is possible that there is 'phantom' data in there (whitespace, etc.) that is causing GAE to think there are more columns than there are.